# preg_match unexpected behaviour

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

This is my code:

```
preg_match('/(?<=groups\\/)\\d+/im', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches)
```

When `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = "/groups/S14022/"`, `$matches` is empty.

When `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = "/groups/S14022"`, `$matches[0]` gets me "S14022".

What do I have to change on the regex to match both cases?

Comment: Add a `\/?` at the end, perhaps?

Comment: Your regexp only matches digits after `groups/`. I don't see how it can ever return `S14022` because of the letter `S`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way,

```
$re = "/(?<=\\/groups\\/)S\\d+\\/?/m"; 
$str = "/groups/S14022/\n/groups/S14022"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

[image]

See Demo https://regex101.com/r/qP2rO5/1

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/tK9zJ9/1) (as in your regex, you are missing `S`):

```
(?<=groups\/)S\d+
```

PHP code:

```
$re = "/(?<=groups\\/)S\\d+/im"; 
$str = "/groups/S14022/\n/groups/S14022"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output of the [sample program](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMNklNdGtkTnRjTlk):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => S14022
            [1] => S14022
        )
)
```

Comment: Please check the code. BTW, you can access the matches by using `$matches[0][0]` and `$matches[0][1]`.